# Terraform variables and count = 0

Tags: terraform

We use the same terraform definitions across all environments. So far that worked well, but now I face a problem I couldn't solve yet. I have a RDS and ElastiCache for a service that I don't need in the demo env that I'm setting up right now, so I set the `count` to `0`. For the other environments, I need to expose them via an output var:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "cc_redis" {
  cluster_id = "cc-${var.env}"
  engine = "redis"
  node_type = "cache.t2.small"
  security_group_ids = ["..."]
  count = "${var.env == "demo" ? 0 : 1}"
}

output "cc_redis_host" {
  value = "${aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.0.address}"
}
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
output.cc_redis_host: Resource 'aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis' not found
for variable 'aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.0.address'
```

I don't mind (much) having a useless variable set, but I can't get it to work in the first place. A simple conditional doesn't resolve this, since terraform evaluates the false side of conditionals even though it's not used. I found [this hack](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16726#issuecomment-346037079) but couldn't get it to work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
output "cc_redis" {
  value = "${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.*.cache_nodes.0.address, list("")), 0)}"
}
```

TF doesn't seem to care that the count may be 0 if you wildcard higher up the chain.

This may output more than you want, but you can parse out what you need from it.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as it lead me to the correct solution, thanks. The value I wanted was `"${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.*.cache_nodes.0.address, list("")), 0)}"`

Comment: How does this work in Terraform 1+? I get an error saying list() is not a function.

Comment: In Terraform 1+ `list()` becomes `tolist()`.  [Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/tolist)  

Also I found this answer helpful working with locals.   
In locals the count object can not be used; and referencing `aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.0` complains about an empty tuple and that the collection has no elements.  

This answer provides a solution to working with count resources in locals.

Answer (score 0):

Change your output to the following:

```
output "cc_redis_host" {
  value = "${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.*. address, list("")), 0)}"
}
```

It is documented somewhere on the terraform website.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. With the space before `address` I get `Error reading config for output cc_redis_host: parse error at 1:86: expected ")" but found "address"` and without the space I still get `output.cc_redis_host: Resource 'aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis' not found for variable 'aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.*.address'`

Comment: try:
output "cc_redis_host" {
  value = "${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.*. cache_nodes, list("")), 0)}"
}

Answer (score 0):

For the people that are coming from google to this thread this is the terraform newer version of handling this:
tolist method with the square brackets is the new approach.

```
value = "${element(concat(aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.*. address, tolist([""])), 0)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put something like below:

```
output "cc_redis" {
  value = var.env == "demo" : null ? aws_elasticache_cluster.cc_redis.cache_nodes.0.address
}
```

Output also accept null, and if its null, it will ignore it at the time of execution.