# Terraform: Conditional creation of a resource based on a variable in .tfvars

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-cloudflare

I have resources defined in `.tf` files that are generic to several applications. I populate many of the fields via a `.tfvars` file. I need to omit some of the resources entirely based on variables in the `.tfvars`.

For example if I have a resource like:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
  zone_id = "${data.cloudflare_zones.domain.zones[0].id}"
  name    = "${var.subdomain}"
  value   = "${var.origin_server}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = true
}
```

But then I declare something like `cloudflare = false` in my `.tfvars` file I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
if var.cloudflare {
  resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
    zone_id = "${data.cloudflare_zones.domain.zones[0].id}"
    name    = "${var.subdomain}"
    value   = "${var.origin_server}"
    type    = "CNAME"
    ttl     = 1
    proxied = true
 }
}
```

I've looked at dynamic blocks but that looks like you can only use those to edit fields and blocks within a resource. I need to be able to ignore an entire resource.

Comment: What version of Terraform?

Comment: I have Terraform v0.12.10 installed now but I could switch to another version if needed.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Add a `count` parameter with a ternary conditional using the variable declared in `.tfvars` like this:

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
  count = var.cloudflare ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = "${data.cloudflare_zones.domain.zones[0].id}"
  name    = "${var.subdomain}"
  value   = "${var.origin_server}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = 1
  proxied = true
}
```

In this example `var.cloudflare` is a boolean declared in the `.tfvars` file. If it is true a count of 1 `record` will be created. If it is false a count of 0 `record` will be created.

After the `count` apply the resource becomes a group, so later in the reference use `0-index` of the group:

```
cloudflare_record.record[0].some_field
```

Comment: Is there a way as well that will allow referencing this resource without using an index? e.g. `cloudflare_record.record[0].name`?

Comment: Index will be required if you use the count feature. If you don't want to hard code the 0 you can use count.index. See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html

Comment: what if resource doesn't get create due to count field, then following line will fail. ```cloudflare_record.record[0].some_field```.how to output this value then

Comment: @VishalSharma - New to this myself, but someone suggested here that you could maybe use an asterisk `*` in place of the brackets (at least when interpolating in a string): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654863/terraform-variables-and-count-0

Comment: @JoelGuerra how should you deal with the output, lets say I want to use some output of cloudflare_record, but since the block has not even executed because of count, how my output will understand?

Comment: maybe use the [try function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/try) to populate output variables

Comment: be nice if there was something a bit cleaner that didn't require us to suddenly use an index like `condition = var.cloudflare ? 1 : 0` (*for people skim-reading do not use this!*)

Comment: in the case of count 0, are the other argument/parameter values required or can you default to null?

Answer (score 39):

Expanding on @Joel Guerra's answer, after you use `count` to determine whether to deploy the resource or not, you can use the `one()` function to refer to the resource without an index (i.e. without having to use `[0]`).

For example, after defining the resource like below

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "record" {
  count = var.cloudflare ? 1 : 0
}
```

Define a local variable like below

```
locals {
  cloudflare_record_somefield = one(cloudflare_record.record[*].some_field)
}
```

Now instead of `cloudflare_record.record[0].some_field`, you can use

```
local.cloudflare_record_somefield
```

If the count is 0 (e.g. `var.cloudflare` is `false` and the resource wasn't created) then `local.cloudflare_record_somefield` would return `null` (instead of returning an error when indexing using `[0]`).

Reference: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one

Answer (score 8):

An issue i'm seeing this with is if the resource your trying to create is already using a for_each then you can't use both count and for_each in the resource.  I'm still trying to find an answer on this will update if I find something better.

Comment: With `for_each` you can do this `for_each = var.condition ? var.list : []`

Comment: and what if I only want to skip the creation of one resource of the for_each and not all of them?

Answer (score 6):

Sample Scenario: You might want to create or not create (toggle / use flag / conditionally create) a VM. But along with the VM, you might also have to create/not create its Load Balancer, Target group, and Security Group etc.

The problem with other answers on the internet is that when you use a ternary operator on a resource and when you try to reference it on some other resource you will always get a reference error or index error or Empty Tuple Error.

To solve this issue while pointing to the conditional resource you can use the `try` syntax

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  count = var.test_flag ? 1 : 0
  cidr_block       = var.vpc_cidr
  instance_tenancy = var.vpc_instance_tenancy

  tags = {
     Name = "${var.cluster_name}-vpc"
  }

}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  count =   try(var.test_flag ? 1 : 0, 0) // try block is important here because it has a dependency, here the VPC, but VPC might not need a try block because it is the parent.

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main[0].id

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.cluster_name}-IG"
  }
}
```

Comment: here the second resource can use count = length(aws_vpc.main) and vpc_id = aws_vpc.main[count.index].id