# dynamic addition in terraform script at runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have terraform with multiple bucket resources and wanted to create a single bucket policy resource with iam_policy_document which can add statements dynamically at certain condition flag gets verified. is there any possible method for this?

Comment: What is your current tf code and what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your code looks like it's very hard to give you an answer, but it vaguely sounds like you could do this with `count`.
Something along the lines of:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  count       = var.create_policy? 1 : 0
  statement {
    sid = "1"

    actions = [
      "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    ]
}
```

The idea is that you set the create policy to `True` or `False`.
If it is set to `True` then the policy will be created.
There is more info about conditional expressions here - https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html

Here is another question on a similar topic - [Terraform: Conditional creation of a resource based on a variable in .tfvars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231309/terraform-conditional-creation-of-a-resource-based-on-a-variable-in-tfvars)