# To create or not to create multiple modules based on user input

Tags: terraform

Looked for an answer for this question in multiple posts but found solutions for a simpler scenarios only.
Let's say I have a module called `a` and this module depends on multiple different modules, let's call them `b` and `c`.

```
module "a" {
   source     = ./a
   depends_on = [module.B, module.C]
   b_id       = module.b.id
   c_id       = module.c.id
}

module "b" {
   source     = ./b
}

module "c" {
   source     = ./c
}
```

In the naive scenario both modules `b` and `c` will be created before we create module `a`, but what if I want to let the user of module `a` to create it's own instances of `b` and `c` and just pass their ids to `a` without us creating `b` and `c`.
I'm aware of the `count` trick on resources detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231309/terraform-conditional-creation-of-a-resource-based-on-a-variable-in-tfvars), but it works only for resources and not modules and to make it work here I will need to apply it to every resource inside the modules which will create a cumbersome code.
I also saw terraform [conditional creation of objects](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/composition#conditional-creation-of-objects) but this solution works good if the main module/resource has just one conditional attribute, what if we have 10 modules that can be provisioned to us by the user or need to be created inline?

Comment: You could have one conditional where true evaluates to a declaration of module `b` and `c` and their outputs mapped to `a` inputs, and false evaluates to no declaration of module `b` and `c`, and `data` is mapped to `a` inputs (which would also not be declared for `true`). I can be more specific with the more specific details, or I can just write up that answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you for the response.
what exactly do you mean with `one conditional`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` in `module` blocks as long as you are using Terraform v0.13 or later:

```
module "a" {
   source = "./a"

   b_id = one(module.b[*].id)
   c_id = one(module.c[*].id)
}

module "b" {
   source = "./b"
   count  = 1
}

module "c" {
   source = "./c"
   count  = 0
}
```

The use of [the `one` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/one) here is to transform what would naturally be a list of either zero or one elements into a single value that may be null. Therefore your module "a" must be ready to accept `null` as a valid value for both `b_id` and `c_id` here, to handle the cases where there are zero instances of those modules.

Note that referring to `module.b` and `module.c` in the arguments of `module "a"` automatically declares dependencies on all of the outputs of those modules, and so it would be redundant to also include `depends_on` in the `module "a"` block. `depends_on` should be used only for "hidden dependencies", which are not reflected in the data flow between resources.

Comment: Thank you dude! great answer!